# Android ListView Updates On Delete But Still Points To Deleted Object?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm working on a ListView that has both an edit and delete button, pressing edit will allow you to edit that object while pressing delete will present a dialog and on confirmation it will delete that object and refresh the list. Everything is working correctly until you delete an item which is before another item, and then after the list refreshes when you try to edit the item it takes you to the deleted one.

Example:

Item 1

Item 2

I delete Item 1 so now my list looks like this:

Item 2

I edit Item 2, and it instead displays Item 1's detail.

From my ListAdapter:

```
private void mDeleteLineItem(final int position)
{
    final LineItem lineItem = mItems.get(position);
    FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
    DeleteConfirmationDialogFragment deleteConfirmationDialogFragment = DeleteConfirmationDialogFragment.newInstance
    (
            mContext.getString(R.string.delete_line_item), mContext.getString(R.string.delete_line_item_confirmation_message),
            new DeleteConfirmationDialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConfirmDeleteButtonPressed() {
                    Log.d("LOG", "List Count Before Delete: " + mItems.size());
                    for(LineItem item : mItems)
                    {
                        Log.d("LOG", "Item Name: " + item.GetItem().GetPartNumber());
                    }
                    lineItem.delete();
                    mItems.remove(position);
                    Log.d("LOG", "List Count After Delete: " + mItems.size());
                    for(LineItem item : mItems)
                    {
                        Log.d("LOG", "Item Name: " + item.GetItem().GetPartNumber());
                    }
                    mListener.onDataSetChanged();
                    ((MainActivity)mContext).UpdateShoppingCartBubble();
                    ((MainActivity)mContext).UpdatePurchaseOrderQueueBubble();
                }

                @Override
                public int describeContents() {
                    return 0;
                }

                @Override
                public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

                }
            }
    );
    deleteConfirmationDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_delete_confirmation");
}
```

From my fragment (this is where the list is being created, I have a listener that allows me to update the list when the item has been deleted)

```
lineItemListAdapter.SetArrayAdapterListener(new ArrayAdapterListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged()
    {
        lineItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(shoppingCartList.isEmpty())
        {
            mDisplayEmptyShoppingCart();
        }
    }
});
```

You probably also notice that I have some logs thrown into the delete. In this example I'm deleting M1P1, this is what I get in those:

```
05-07 08:25:11.740    List Count Before Delete: 2
05-07 08:25:11.743    Item Name: M1P1
05-07 08:25:11.743    Item Name: C1P7
05-07 08:25:11.826    List Count After Delete: 1
05-07 08:25:11.827    Item Name: C1P7
```

Other information that might be useful, I'm using ActiveAndroid for the ORM, you'll see that I'm deleting the item before I actually remove it from the list which makes me all the more confused as to why it's still loading the object as if it's still there.

Any idea what could be causing this? I'm going to continue to look into this issue to see if I can figure out what's going on, but it's so bizarre I figured I'd make a post on here before I slam my head against my desk anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, and unfortunately I didn't post the method that was causing problems.

```
viewHolder.ibEditLineItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        mEditLineItem(item);
    }
});
```

That was posted above, and the issue was this was holding the item. So when I passed it into the method to edit the item...

```
private void mEditLineItem(LineItem item)
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("is_edit", true);
    bundle.putInt("item_id", lineItem.GetItem().GetId());
    bundle.putLong("aa_line_item_id", lineItem.getId());
    bundle.putInt("quantity", lineItem.GetQuantity());
    bundle.putLong("aa_supplier_id", lineItem.GetSupplier().getId());

    PartDetailFragment partDetailFragment = new PartDetailFragment();
    partDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.flFragmentSection, partDetailFragment).commit();
}
```

It was still reference the deleted item. So in order to fix it I am now passing in the position of the list item which then grabs the current item at that position. Updated code:

```
viewHolder.ibEditLineItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        mEditLineItem(position);
    }
});

private void mEditLineItem(int position)
{
    LineItem lineItem = mItems.get(position);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("is_edit", true);
    bundle.putInt("item_id", lineItem.GetItem().GetId());
    bundle.putLong("aa_line_item_id", lineItem.getId());
    bundle.putInt("quantity", lineItem.GetQuantity());
    bundle.putLong("aa_supplier_id", lineItem.GetSupplier().getId());

    PartDetailFragment partDetailFragment = new PartDetailFragment();
    partDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.flFragmentSection, partDetailFragment).commit();
}
```